# How to kill previous AJAX calls in DataTables

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

Ok i have a function like

So when this function is called the AJAX request is made but if I again call the same function. The current request is made but the previous call is not killed. I want the datatable to kill any previous calls and run only the latest one.

I'm not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 8):

> This is how I do it with DataTables 1.10.16

```
var table = $('#table').DataTable({
    ajax: {
        url: '/datatable',
        type: 'POST',
        beforeSend: function() {
            if (table.hasOwnProperty('settings')) {
                table.settings()[0].jqXHR.abort();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: i am getting an error: 'Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined'

Comment: @MehmoodMemon try to replace line 6 with this: if (table && table.hasOwnProperty('settings')) {

Comment: This also removes "Processing..." dialog after aborting previous request.

You need to add ``$('#DataTables_Table_0_processing').show();`` after 7 line

Answer (score 3):

It might help someone

```
        preDrawCallback: function(settings) {
            if ($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#table')) {
                var dt = $('#table').DataTable();

                //Abort previous ajax request if it is still in process.
                var settings = dt.settings();
                if (settings[0].jqXHR) {
                    settings[0].jqXHR.abort();
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

The following worked for me...

```
var elTable = jQuery('table#myDataTable');
var oTable = elTable.DataTable();
oTable.context[0].jqXHR.abort()
```

Answer (score 2):

I have Datatable 1.10.5 . Its worked.

```
           if ($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#table')) {
               var dt = $('#table').DataTable();

               //Abort previous ajax request if it is still in process.
               var settings = dt.settings();
               if (settings[0].jqXHR) {
                   settings[0].jqXHR.abort();
               }
           }
       }
```

I also did the call delay as follows.

````
       var $searchBox = $(tableId + "_filter input[type='search']");
       $searchBox.off();

       var searchDebouncedFn = debounce(function () {
           $(tableId).DataTable().search($searchBox.val()).draw();
       }, 300);

       $searchBox.on("keyup", searchDebouncedFn);
   }

   /* from https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function */
   function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
       var timeout;
       return function () {
           var context = this, args = arguments;
           var later = function () {
               timeout = null;
               if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
           };
           var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
           clearTimeout(timeout);
           timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
           if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
       };
   };

   debounceSearch('#table') ```
````

Answer (score 1):

I think these threads will be helpful:

[Abort previous ajax call in datatables 1.10](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/20329/abort-previous-ajax-call-in-datatables-1-10)

[How can I stop all the currently ongoing Ajax queries that DataTables instance have started?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26531937/how-can-i-stop-all-the-currently-ongoing-ajax-queries-that-datatables-instance-h)

It looks like you could add something like this to the first line of your function:

```
function load(id) {
    if($('#videos_list').DataTable().settings.jqXHR) {
        $('#videos_list').DataTable().settings.jqXHR.abort()
    }
    $("#table_wrapper").mask("");
    etc...
```